# ModelForm has no model class specified Error at Django

Tags: python, django, web

I tried to build a simple registration from using django, but somehow it does not work
here's my model :

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    voted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self): return self.name
```

Here is my Form :

```
class User_data(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        form = User
        fields = ("name", "email")
```

Here's my View.py :

```
def register(response):
    form = User_data
    if response.method == 'post':
        form = User_data(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(response)
    return render(response,'voting/voting.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

what did I miss? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify the model fo a [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/) with the `model` attribute in the `Meta` class, so:

```
class User_data(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User  # ← model, not form
        fields = ('name', 'email')
```

Furthermore a successful POST request normally should result in a redirect to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* architectural pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get):

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def register(request):
    form = User_data
    if request.method == 'POST':  # ← POST, not post
        form = User_data(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(index)
    return render(request,'voting/voting.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```